# if(x) vs if(!!x) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the difference between the below codes in **JavaScript**?

```
if(x)
 doSomething();
```

and

```
if(!!x)
 doSomething();
```

Comment: This is a weird thing to do in an `if`, but totally normal to use elsewhere to force a boolean like `let y = !!x`.

Comment: There is no difference at all, because the way the expression in an `if` test is evaluated is exactly the same as what `!!x` means.

Comment: Outside of an `if` test, of course, there is a difference: `!!` converts any value to a boolean value according to the standard interpretation of expressions in contexts like an `if` test.

Answer (score 2):

No logical difference - the JS runtime will automatically figure out the "truthiness" of a statement.

I've seen this in a few places before (or the even more fun `if(!!!x)` instead of `if(!x)`) in the past.

<opinion>
I think it has something to do with older JS runtimes that did a poor job of truthiness testing.  I believe this to be an obsolete and overly verbose, if valid, construct.</opinion>

Comment: RE: opinion - don't think this was ever the case. I've seen it used to explicitly denote that what's passed into the `if` is **not** a boolean. So there are fewer surprises after seeing the `if` itself. But it's mostly a coding style thing.

Comment: I'm assuming "older" here means from the 20th century, because I haven't seen anything that intensely weird since the "JScript" days.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a rationale for polluting code with nonsense.